# Microsoft implementation of generating SSL certificate

Tags: c, windows, ssl

I am building a server/client application and I would like to use Microsoft's SSL instead of a 3rd party library such as OpenSSL.

I have came across this example code on the MSDN:
Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/using-sspi-with-a-windows-sockets-server

Client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/using-sspi-with-a-windows-sockets-client

I am looking through the code and it appears that it is using a function `AcquireCredentialsHandle` which from my understanding just uses existing credentials (cert?) found on the system.

I would like to, if possible, create my own certificate on the fly each time I connect to the server. This way the cert is changed each time and if anyone were to get my cert then it would only be useful for the specific set of traffic.

Comment: If your client was to accept any random certificate from the server, why bother at all?

Comment: After a connection is made, the client would send a key to the server that would tell me if it is an actual client. To make sure random things are not connecting to the server.

Comment: That will authenticate the client. But still the server authentication is useless if you change certs all the time.

Comment: The server would also generate a new cert each time it is ran.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I might not be understanding this fully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208578/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-doritos).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "the cert is changed each time and if anyone were to get my cert then it would only be useful for the specific set of traffic." This is not how/what for certificates are used, they are used for authentication. And even with long lasting certificates, with modern TLS, Perfect Forward Secrecy is achieved or said otherwise a key is generated only for that specific traffic, and lost as soon as the traffic stops which means even a cold analysis of the encrypted traffic would not yield information to decrypt it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy